# Set Text above image

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, textview

[image]

I want to set the Text name above the image. How can i do it? I have a listview and a separate imageview. But i was searching for some name in a search box. The result will display the image with text. I want to display the text above my image.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingTop="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:textColor="#0099CC"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout as the parent view group.  You can use margins/padding to position views wherever you want:

http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/3/

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to accomplish this are:

In your `listview.xml` change your `LinearLayout` to a vertical orientation and define the `TextView` first.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              ...
              android:orientation="vertical">
          <TextView  .....></TextView>
          <ImageView .....></ImageVIew>  
</LinearLayout>
```

**Or** you can change your `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` and use the `android:layout_below` attribute on the imageview.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              ...>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    .....></TextView>
          <ImageView .....
                     android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"></ImageVIew>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add line 'android:orientation="vertical"' to Your **listview.xml**
(LinearLayout section)

so Your listview.xml will look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5px"                
                android:paddingTop="5px"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ImageView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="20px"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
android:textColor="#0099CC">
            </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```